# How to use immutable.js with RTK (redux toolkit)?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm migrating legacy Redux code to RTK.

With my legacy code base I was using Immutable.js (for immutability purposes), I don't need it anymore for the new code I'm gonna write, but I would like for the legacy code to keep working without touching it, and while using `configureStore` from RTK. But my apps throws :

> Invariant failed: A state mutation was detected between dispatches, in the path 'app._values._tail.array.0._values._root.array.0.array.16._defaultValues.gcm.__hash'. This may cause incorrect behavior. (https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#do-not-mutate-state)

I get it, it's because I change the object instance, I can disable the error doing so :

```js
immutableCheck: false,
serializableCheck: false,
```

but IMO it disables too much, I would like to keep these settings on, but for Immutable.js to bypass the immutability check.
I found this piece of outdated code that looks like what I'm trying to achieve

```js
// Augment middleware to consider Immutable.JS iterables serializable
const isSerializable = (value) =>
  Iterable.isIterable(value) || isPlain(value)
const getEntries = (value) =>
  Iterable.isIterable(value) ? value.entries() : Object.entries(value)
const serializableMiddleware = createSerializableStateInvariantMiddleware({
  isSerializable: () => true // all values will be accepted
  isSerializable,
  getEntries,
})
const store = configureStore({
  reducer,
  middleware: [serializableMiddleware]
})
```

here https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/pull/141/files but it's not working, `Iterable` is now `Collection` and has no `isIterable` function, I've tried `isImmutable` but it's not working either.

Now the file looks like this : https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/master/docs/api/otherExports.mdx, there's no trace of Immutable.js.

What can I do ?

*cross-post: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/discussions/3539*

Comment: Please read the excerpts of the tags when adding them to your question; [rtk] is a tag for Real Time Kinetic, not Redux Toolkit.

Comment: @HereticMonkey my bad sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@EskiMojo14, one of the maintainers on RTK was able to [find a solution](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/discussions/3539#discussioncomment-6219348) for me :

> the serializableCheck and immutableCheck are two separate checks, and we want you to customise them using [`getDefaultMiddleware`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/getDefaultMiddleware#customizing-the-included-middleware).
>
> For example, something like the below (untested) code might work:
>
> ```
> import { configureStore, isImmutableDefault, isPlain } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
> import { isImmutable } from "immutable";
>
> const store = configureStore({
>   reducer,
>   middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
>     getDefaultMiddleware({
>       immutableCheck: {
>         isImmutable: (value) => isImmutable(value) || isImmutableDefault(value),
>       },
>       serializableCheck: {
>         isSerializable: (value) => isImmutable(value) || isPlain(value),
>         getEntries: (value) =>
>           isImmutable(value) ? value.entries() : Object.entries(value),
>       },
>     }),
> });
> ```